# GO using interfaces as fields

Tags: interface, go

I'm going through [An Introduction to Programming in Go](http://www.golang-book.com/9) and trying to grasp interfaces.  I feel like I have an ok idea of what they are and why we would need them but I'm having trouble using them.  At the end of the section they have

> Interfaces can also be used as fields:
>
> ```
> type MultiShape struct {
>     shapes []Shape
> }
> ```
>
> We can even turn MultiShape itself into a Shape by giving it an area method:
>
> ```
> func (m *MultiShape) area() float64 {
>     var area float64
>     for _, s := range m.shapes {
>         area += s.area()
>     }
>     return area
> }
> ```
>
> Now a MultiShape can contain Circles, Rectangles or even other MultiShapes.

I don't know how to use this.  My understanding of this is `MultiShape` can have a `Circle` and `Rectangle` in it's `slice`

This is the example code I'm working with

```
package main

import ("fmt"; "math")


type Shape interface {
    area() float64
}

type MultiShape struct {
    shapes []Shape
}

func (m *MultiShape) area() float64 {
    var area float64
    for _, s := range m.shapes {
        area += s.area()
    }
    return area
}

// ===============================================
// Rectangles

type Rectangle struct {
    x1, y1, x2, y2 float64
}

func distance(x1, y1, x2, y2 float64) float64 {
    a := x2 - x1
    b := y2 - y1
    return math.Sqrt(a*a + b*b)
}

func (r *Rectangle) area() float64 {
    l := distance(r.x1, r.y1, r.x1, r.y2)
    w := distance(r.x1, r.y1, r.x2, r.y1)
    return l*w
}

// ===============================================
// Circles

type Circle struct {
    x, y, r float64
}

func (c * Circle) area() float64 {
    return math.Pi * c.r*c.r
}

// ===============================================

func totalArea(shapes ...Shape) float64 {
    var area float64
    for _, s := range shapes {
        area += s.area()
    }
    return area
}

func main() {

    c := Circle{0,0,5}
    fmt.Println(c.area())

    r := Rectangle{0, 0, 10, 10}
    fmt.Println(r.area())

    fmt.Println(totalArea(&r, &c))

    //~ This doesn't work but this is my understanding of it
    //~ m := []MultiShape{c, r}
    //~ fmt.Println(totalArea(&m))

}
```

Can someone help me with this?  I have a python background so if there is some kind of link between the two that would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Shape interface {
    area() float64
}

type MultiShape struct {
    shapes []Shape
}

func (m *MultiShape) area() float64 {
    var area float64
    for _, s := range m.shapes {
        area += s.area()
    }
    return area
}

type Rectangle struct {
    x1, y1, x2, y2 float64
}

func (s *Rectangle) area() float64 {
    x := math.Abs(s.x2 - s.x1)
    y := math.Abs(s.y2 - s.y1)
    return x * y
}

func (s *Rectangle) distance() float64 {
    x := s.x2 - s.x1
    y := s.y2 - s.y1
    return math.Sqrt(x*x + y*y)
}

type Circle struct {
    x, y, r float64
}

func (s *Circle) area() float64 {
    return math.Pi * s.r * s.r
}

func main() {
    r1 := Rectangle{1, 1, 4, 4}
    fmt.Println(r1.area())
    r2 := Rectangle{2, 4, 3, 6}
    fmt.Println(r2.area())
    c := Circle{10, 10, 2}
    fmt.Println(c.area())
    m := MultiShape{[]Shape{&r1, &r2, &c}}
    fmt.Println(m.area())
}
```

Output:

```
9
2
12.566370614359172
23.566370614359172
```

Comment: I have that much, the part I don't get is the `MultiShape`.